# XCode 5 cannot find binaries

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoapods

Since I started using CocoaPods, I've been having weird location related messages all the time, and some arch-related ones too.

I've been trying the whole day to figure out why it was happening, until I create a new Xcode project from scratch and realize the issue wasn't project-related all along.

Here's what's happening:
[image]

I always get those everywhere as well:
[image]

Not sure if related but I get those often too:
[image]

Anybody has those as well? What should I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had to switch Build Active Architectures Only for debug to Yes and it let the build run.